# SquareUp Adding Customer to a group and setting recurring time

Tags: php, square-connect

I am searching through Squareup API and i can not find a way to add Customer to an existing group and set Recurring timeframe. Can you help me with this?

I saw a guide for charging cards on file but there is no line in that code that sets recurring for example every two months.

By the way i am using PHP. Is anything of this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you must initiate recurring transactions yourself (with a cron job for example). You cannot specify a customer and a timeframe for Square to bill the customer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the flow is like this: I create Customer, save card for that customer and then bill that card using cron. Is this correct?

Comment: yeah, that is the gist of it. You call the Charge endpoint with the customer and the card id instead of the card nonce that you would normally charge with.

Comment: Great. Thank you.